# Getting value into crystal report as integer/number

Tags: crystal-reports

> Blockquote

Hi All,

I am writing ref cursor to pull the values from oracle to crystal reports. everything is working fine. I have 5 columns in my table out of which one is number datatype and remaining are in varchar2 datatype. when i am using the code below i am getting all the values as a string into crystal report. but i want to get one field as number and remaining as string. please check the below code for example. How to pull the first column1 as integer to the report.

> **code written in the content:** 'public string column1 { get; set; } public string column2 { get; set; } public string column3 { get; set;
>   } public string column4 { get; set; } public string column5 { get;
>   set; }'

**code written in main to pull the data** ' objParamCnt.column1= oraReader["column1"].ToString();  objParamCnt.column2 = oraReader["column2"].ToString();  objParamCnt.column3 = oraReader["column3"].ToString();  objParamCnt.column4 = oraReader["column4"].ToString();  objParamCnt.column5 = oraReader["column5"].ToString();'

Answer (score 0):

It can be done two steps:

1. in content code

public int column1 {get; set;}

1. in main code

objParamCnt.column1 = Convert.ToInt32(oraReader["column1"]);

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: Great! It really worked. I am expert in Crystal and never touched the C# code that is why i am facing problem to pull the different data types from the tables. As work around i am converting all these in crystal only. Now with your solution i can pull the string and int values. Could you please give one example for date and clob(Images). Because i have some images in oracle table and i have to get those into crystal through c#. my ref cursors are ready but want to know how to get those datatypes as it is from c3. thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pleased that it worked for you. Please mark it as answer (tick it) to let other know that this works.

in case of Date you just need to revise the step 1,2 and replacing int with DateTime i.e Convet.ToDateTime().....

Comment: In case of images you need to store them as Byte array, so that on retrieving you get an array of Byte, after that you can manipulate it quite easily